# What's the idea behind creating objects using Object.assign

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through [this Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#creating-a-dispatcher) tutorial and the objects are created there like this:

```
var AppDispatcher = assign({}, Dispatcher.prototype, {

  /**
   * A bridge function between the views and the dispatcher, marking the action
   * as a view action.  Another variant here could be handleServerAction.
   * @param  {object} action The data coming from the view.
   */
  handleViewAction: function(action) {
    this.dispatch({
      source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
      action: action
    });
  }

});
```

They use `Object.assign` through polyfill. Since `Object.assign` copies all properties to the object as opposed to `Object.create(prototype)`, I'm wondering what their motivation is to copy the properties directly onto `AppDispatcher`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's just creating a copy of `Dispatcher`, based on its prototype.

If you were to do `AppDispatcher = Dispatcher;`, and then you mutate `AppDispatcher`, you would also be mutating `Dispatcher`. `assign` in this case just creates a safe copy, and then lets you assign properties to that *copy*.

Comment: can you elaborate on that part `...based on its prototype`? And how the same can be accomplished without using `assign`?

Comment: @Maximus, You could do `var AppDispatcher = Object.create(Dispatcher.prototype)` and then set `AppDispatcher.handleViewAction = /* whatever */`. The way they do it is just for convenience. Makes it more concise. There's nothing fancy or hidden about it, it's just another way of doing it.

Comment: with `Object.create`, properties available on `Dispatcher.prototype` will be accessible through prototype chain, but I thought that `assign` copies these properties and makes them own properties of `AppDispatcher`, no?

Comment: @Maximus, if the polyfill `assign` directly mimicks `Object.assign` from ES6, then yes, `assign` will copy all of the prototype's properties directly onto the `AppDispatcher`. I haven't looked in the source of `assign`, but I assume that that's the case.

Comment: So then `Object.create` approach is different, right?

Comment: @Maximus, correct, slightly different, because you would be accessing the properties through the prototype chain when using `Object.create`. Both approaches grant you access to the properties in `Dispatcher` as the underlying paradigm. The policy is the same, but the mechanism is slightly different.

Comment: @Maximus, however, I am not sure what their motivation is to copy the properties directly onto `AppDispatcher`.